# Reshape object into another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

I am trying to use pro-gallery library in my project and it accepts an array of image like this :

```js
const items = [
  {
    // Image item:
    itemId: "sample-id",
    mediaUrl: "https://i.picsum.photos/id/674/200/300.jpg?hmac=kS3VQkm7AuZdYJGUABZGmnNj_3KtZ6Twgb5Qb9ITssY",
    metaData: {
      type: "image",
      height: 10,
      width: 100,
      title: "sample-title",
      description: "sample-description",
    },
  },
  ...
]
```

But my own array of items looks like this, how would you do to extract interesting fields and recreate a new array ?

```js
"products": [
  {
    "_id": "618e2787d193ae4a3068cae5",
    "name": "Photo",
    "category": "cuba",
    "image": "https://someimage.com/dqve1.jpg",
    "price": 20,
    "countInStock": 12,
    "brand": "John Doe",
    "description": "Description example...",
    "seller": "618aeab0f82f5854ec925a5f",
  },   
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you'd like to flatten your object. So if I understand the question correctly, this solution should work perfectly.

You can use `forEach` to iterate through your array of objects, then use `Objects.entries` to extract the key value pairs of the objects and insert them into a new object in our preferred formatting. Finally, we push that object onto our array.

```js
const items = [
    {
        itemId: "sample-id",
        mediaUrl:
            "https://i.picsum.photos/id/674/200/300.jpg?hmac=kS3VQkm7AuZdYJGUABZGmnNj_3KtZ6Twgb5Qb9ITssY",
        metaData: {
            type: "image",
            height: 10,
            width: 100,
            title: "sample-title",
            description: "sample-description",
        }},
    {
        itemId: "secondSample",
        mediaUrl:
            "https://i.picsum.photos/id/674/200/300.jpg?hmac=kS3VQkm7AuZdYJGUABZGmnNj_3KtZ6Twgb5Qb9ITssY",
        metaData: {
            type: "image",
            height: 100,
            width: 200,
            title: "second image",
            description: "sample-description",
        }},
    {
        itemId: "sample-id-3",
        mediaUrl:
            "https://i.picsum.photos/id/674/200/300.jpg?hmac=kS3VQkm7AuZdYJGUABZGmnNj_3KtZ6Twgb5Qb9ITssY",
        metaData: {
            type: "image",
            height: 1028,
            width: 130,
            title: "sample-title-3",
            description: "sample-description-3",
        },
    },
];

let newItems = {"items": [
    ]};

items.forEach((item, index) => {
    let thisItem = {};
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
        if(typeof value === 'object'){
            for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(value)) {
                thisItem[k] = v;

            }
        } else {
            thisItem[key] = value;

        }
    }
    newItems.items.push(thisItem);
});

console.log(newItems);
```

Comment: thank you, I've learned something :)